# (App Script) How to merge row with same data and delete duplicate data with App script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create mail merge. But I have some problem , I need to send data more than 1 row in same mail. So, I merge it before send . but after merge , It's have a duplicate data in 1 cell because It's only check in first column not all column . Pls help
[The sheet I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6E0ZI.png)

[The sheet after merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj77p.png)

[image]

[And this is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xof5Z.png)

[image]

and this is the code I used

```
function mergerow() {
  var firstRow = 2;
  var firstCol = 1;
  var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sht.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, sht.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1, sht.getLastColumn() - firstCol + 1).sort(1);
  /*
  sht.appendRow(['***','***','Control-z one more time','***','***']); //need a throwaway row to get last data element out since I'm moving out element[i-1]
  */
  var datR = sht.getDataRange();
  var lastRow = datR.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = datR.getLastColumn();
  var datA = datR.getValues();
  sht.getRange(2,1,lastRow - firstRow + 1,lastCol - firstCol + 1).clearContent().setWrap(true);
  var datoutA = [];
  var k=1;
  var n = 0;
  for(var i = 0;i < datA.length; i++)
  {
    if(i > 1)
    {
      if(datA[i][0] == datA[i-1][0])
      {
        k++;  //k is the number of consecutive matching values
      }
      else
      {
        datoutA[n] = [];
        if(k == 1)
        {
          // if k = 1 the datA[i-1] row gets copied into output array
          for(var c = 0;c < datA[i-1].length; c++)
          {
            datoutA[n][c]=datA[i-1][c];
          }
        }
        else
        {
          //i-1 to i-k rows get merged and copied into output array
          var firstTime = true;
          for(var a = 1;a <= k;a++)//input rows
          {            
            for(var b = 0;b < datA[i].length -1;b++)//input columns
            {
                if(a > 1 || b > 0) //no delimiter for first row or first column 
                {
                  datoutA[n][b] += ', ';
                }
               if(firstTime || b == 0)// straight assignment for first row and running sum after that same with first column because we only want one of them because they're all the same.
               {
                 datoutA[n][b] = datA[i - a][b];
               }
               else
               {
                 datoutA[n][b] += datA[i - a][b];
               }
            }
            if(firstTime)//first assignment then running sums for last column
            {
              datoutA[n][datA[i].length - 1] = Number(datA[i - a][datA[i].length-1]);
            }
            else
            {
              datoutA[n][datA[i].length - 1] += Number(datA[i - a][datA[i].length-1]);
            }

            firstTime=false;
          }
          var end = 'is near';
        }
        k=1; //consecutive counter
        n++; //datoutA index
      }

    }

  } 
  var datoutR = sht.getRange(2, 1, datoutA.length , datoutA[0].length);
  datoutR.setValues(datoutA);
  var colwidth = 250;
  sht.setColumnWidth(2, colwidth);
  sht.setColumnWidth(3, colwidth);
  sht.setColumnWidth(4, colwidth);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pattern 1:

About `but after merge , It's have a duplicate data in 1 cell because It's only check in first column not all column .`, for example, when your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var datoutR = sht.getRange(2, 1, datoutA.length , datoutA[0].length);
datoutR.setValues(datoutA);
```

#### To:

```
var temp = v => [...new Set(v.split(",").map(vv => vv.trim()))].join(", ");
datoutA = datoutA.map(([a, b, c, d, e, f]) => [a, temp(b), temp(c), temp(d), temp(e), f]);
var datoutR = sht.getRange(2, 1, datoutA.length, datoutA[0].length);
datoutR.setValues(datoutA);
```

### Pattern 2:

When I saw your script, I thought that the script might be able to be simple a little. For example, the retrieved range can be declared only one time. And, the number of for-loop might be able to be reduced. And also, from your showing sample input, I guessed that you might have wanted to separate the values of "Fname" and "Lname". If my understanding of your expected conversion is correct, as pattern 2, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function mergerow() {
  var firstRow = 2;
  var firstCol = 1;
  var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // --- I modified the below script.
  var range = sht.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, sht.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1, sht.getLastColumn() - firstCol + 1).sort(1).setWrap(true);
  var values = [...range.getValues().reduce((m, [a, b, c, d, e, f]) => {
    var key = a + b;
    if (m.has(key)) {
      var [aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff] = m.get(key);
      m.set(key, [aa, bb, [c.trim(), ...cc], [d.trim(), ...dd], [e.trim(), ...ee], ff + (f || 0)]);
    } else {
      m.set(key, [a, b, [c.trim()], [d.trim()], [e.trim()], f || 0]);
    }
    return m;
  }, new Map()).values()].map(([a, b, c, d, e, f]) => [a, b, [...new Set(c)].join(", "), [...new Set(d)].join(", "), [...new Set(e)].join(", "), f]);
  range.clearContent().offset(0, 0, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  // ---

  var colwidth = 250;
  sht.setColumnWidth(2, colwidth);
  sht.setColumnWidth(3, colwidth);
  sht.setColumnWidth(4, colwidth);
}
```

- When this script is run, I thought that your expected input and output situations will be achieved.
- Unfortunately, the values of column "F" are not shown in your sample input and output situation. So, from your showing script, I guessed that the values of column "F" might be a number, and you want to sum the number for each row.

### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided expected input and output situation. When you change the Spreadsheet or the structure of your actual Spreadsheet is different from your showing sample Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)